# how can i pass the data from one view to another using client side only?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc-4

My scenario is that i am building a framework like web application where user can build his own page and he/she can preview it. Giving the preview functionality on the same page is pretty easy but i want to give it on a new pop up window which will open on a button click. Here i want to pass a JavaScript variable from one view to another(may be an HTML page),and i don't want to use server for this task because the data is pretty temporary so at the client side how can i pass the variable using JavaScript or j-Query ?

Comment: do you need to pass variables between existing/opened pages or only from open pages to newly created/opened pages?

Comment: while using it on the same page i don't need to do any thing much but copying the data(inner Html) of one Div to another but for passing the data i have no idea how to do it.

Comment: @justinL i need to pass the variable on newly opened pop up page on the button click

Comment: you can use window.parent.document.getElementbyId

Answer (score 0):

```
in using a jquery plugin have a js for cookie.the following example can useful for u.
first set value into cookie the following way
 <script src="js/jquery.cookie.js"></script>
   $.cookie("Token",value);
in another page u get this cookie using cookie name. 
   var Cookie=$.cookie("Token");
when  u need to pass a value use this source on that page with jquery plugin.
<script src="js/jquery.cookie.js"></script>
```

Comment: the coding part sounds good and understandable. but i am not able found appropriate Js file, i found "jquery.cookies.js" which is not working properly.

Comment: It is working now. $.cookies.set(name,value); and $.cookies.get(name); works for me.

Comment: hey it is working but don't know how to handle it some times it gives output sometimes it don't, any help?

Comment: i find out the problem that cookie can store the data up to 4 KB, hence when size reaches beyond 4 KB it refuse to store it. How can i overcome this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

```
if pass the one page to another page means simple to use cookies.otherwise using only on inside single page  use the following code.
var a;
var b;
var x=10;
var y=mark;
<button onclick="myfunction(\''+x+'\',\''+y+'\');">click</button>
function myfunction(x,y)
{
a=x;
b=y;
console.log(a,b);
}
```